# What is the story behind your question?

Tags: discussion, international-sites

Please let me quote [@CypherPotato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24529/cypherpotato) (a free form translation [from Portuguese](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7927/17539) through the lens of Google Translate):

> I play a game which is called ShellShock Live. It is a 2D scenario game with two (or more) tanks that have different kinds of weapons. The goal of the game is to aim and shoot the rival.
>
> [image]
>
> I have been playing the game since its beta, the time it was written in Flash. When I started playing, I quickly leveled up and I hit the top 20 in the world. I was part of a worldwide clan and felt very respected.
>
> Because I wanted to be perfect at shooting, I started looking for a good aim to practice. I cloned [a repository](https://github.com/forceprojectx/sslAimAssist) and started implementing my own aimbot hack: the aimbot traced how a shot would go and where it would hit.
>
> The implementation worked well and nobody noticed my aimbot but soon a problem arose: they added wind to the game. The wind swung bullets to the left or to the right somehow. This made my bot not working and I started missing the shots.
>
> I tried to find ways around the problem, but I couldn't. As a result I asked a question: [How to implement wind in a path equation?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129282/17539). Of course I did not mention that I needed it for a hack (at the end the question became the best one I have ever asked on the site).
>
> I started getting answers but none of them worked. I kept trying and trying and trying. To take another try I needed to close and open the game, so I was doing it all the time. It seemed strange to another gamer, so they asked me:
>
> > Why are you opening and closing the game all the time?
>
> At that point it became obvious that I was doing “wrong things."
>
> I could not find a solution until the last answer, the accepted one, which solved my problem. My use of the aimbot didn't last long. I was banned in the game. And knew why. I was really upset. I emailed the developer explaining the work I did and explaining how he could work around it. I highlighted assembly obfuscation which should make injection of the hack into the game impossible.
>
> And I was unbanded after a while. I was discouraged, so I stopped using hacks as well as playing the game at all. I played again only one year after that. When I came back I was among the top 25,000 in the world. Today I am among 13,000 and maybe one day I will reach the top 20 again.
>
> That's the story of how a physical formula and Stack Overflow helped me do something bad and get penalised for it :D

---

What was it all about? About a contest that we had on international sites!

A question on Stack Overflow is just the tip of an iceberg. As I see it, even a simple question on the site may be preceded by a long series of unsuccessful attempts and painful searches for new ways to solve a problem (and sometimes tough conversations with the manager or bans in online games). For example, once I have deleted an entire product server with `rm -rf . /*` (I made a typo, a space between `.` and `/`), what caused a question «[How to avoid typos when removing a directory in the terminal?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1017949/6)».

Throughout September, international sites' users had been sharing their stories, like the one above, that preceded their questions on Stack Overflows ([SOja](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3075/78), [SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7925/17539), [SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4306/10), [SOru](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9469/6)). After reading the stories one might know:

- [How a tiny little top bar in Eclipse is called](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4357/10)
- [What to do if one decompresses a zipped archive near a folder with the same name](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3081/78)
- [What better to use if or try/catch](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9490/6)
- [Why it is important to not give up debugging an app, even if you need to show the app to your teacher in 15 minutes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4363/10)
- [What will happen if you execute `sudo rm -rf --.*` in the terminal on your Ubuntu machine and why backups are important](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4354/10)

Let me thank everyone who participated! All stories are amazing! Please go and read all of them.

By the way, what is the story behind your question on any Stack Exchange site? Please share it with the community in an answer to this question! =)

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here, but I'm afraid *panem et circenses* just won't fly with the community right now. There are other priorities SE staff should handle IMHO. Nice try, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi why assume ill intent?

Comment: @Luuklag, I'm not. On the contrary, I can see the good intentions that triggered the move. Just saying now is not the right time for this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this contest started [by September 1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4306/83), before _everything_ happened.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi while I partially agree with you and I've suspended my 10k-user actions, I think it doesn't prevent us from having some fun. I'd post answer here if I could think of one.

Comment: @fedorqui, *many things* happened before September 1st. However, why resume this contest *now?* I just wanted to point out this may not be the best time to interact with the community in this way. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ok ok I see your point. It is only that the contest was held between 1 and 30 September and the results were announced to be announced (:P) by October 10, so today was the stipulated day to have this post.

Comment: @fedorqui, sorry, I'm a little on the edge. Today is also the day the new CoC is supposed to be presented to us, and I've been projecting all kinds of supputations about what it will contain and how it will impact us, so to me this question looks "out of focus", so to speak.

Comment: I like the idea behind this but it doesn't work too well on a site like SFF (my home in the network). 99% of the time the story behind the question is going to be I saw/read this, had a question, asked it. The real interesting stories come from the answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, I agree today comes with a very important thing and this can confuse a bit. Nevertheless, I remember reading in _Les Misérables_ how weddings were taking place in Paris during the peak moments of the July Revolution. Big places have space for many things.

Comment: @fedorqui nice metaphor, I see this as holding a small party at school while bullies still roam free in that same school and making trouble. :-)

Comment: @Shadow good one! In any case, just wanted to say that this was scheduled. Didn't intend to play the _what is the metaphor behind your comment_ :D

Comment: This is a really nice idea, but would probably do *much* better when the current crisis has faded a bit